# How to hide and show one popup at a time using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

i am using table, wherein in td i have a field called details, if i click on that the modal opens below, if i click on second row, first row v l remain opened along with second, so i want to open the recently clicked one and close the rest.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top:34px;" *ngIf= "medicationTableValue.length >0">
      <p-table #dt [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="medicationTableValue">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
          <tr role="row">
            <th width="200">Name</th>
            <th class="line-height15">Reason for Taking</th>
            <th width="60">Details</th>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
          <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
            <td>{{rowData.name}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.Reason}}</td>
            <td>
              <a class="details" id="details1" (click)="detailsList(rowData)">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngIf="rowData.showDetailsList">
            <td class="nes_table" colspan="8">
              <div>
                <table class="w-100 table table-bordered">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="150">Name</td>
                      <td>{{rowData.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td width="150">Date Started</td>
                      <td>{{rowData.date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
      </p-table>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
 detailsList(rowData) {
    rowData.showDetailsList = !rowData.showDetailsList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing is that you have toggle property `showDetailsList` for each row. Now your requirement is to hide others and show the latest one.

So what we need to do is to set `showDetailsList` to `false` for each row of table and then set `showDetailsList` of current row.

So your code should look like -

### in ts

```
 detailsList(tableData, rowData) {
    let isHidden = rowData.showDetailsList;
    tableData.forEach(row=>{row.showDetailsList = false;}) //reset all rows of table
    rowData.showDetailsList = !isHidden;                      
  }
```

### in html

```
(click)="detailsList(medicationTableValue, rowData)"
```

> Note : the Implementation is given on some assumption on tableData and its properties. Make the changes as per your table and row properties.

Comment: Thanks for response, its working but on click of outside this popup is not closing

Comment: In that case you need to check if the user is clicking outside of component. If he does that then you can fire code snippet to hide all rows. You can refers this to see how to capture if the user is clicked outside - http://4dev.tech/2016/03/angular2-tutorial-detecting-clicks-outside-the-component/

Comment: Sorry, i mean if i again click on that row only it must get hided

Comment: We need to capture the current row state `showDetailsList` and reverse it.  Answer is updated accordingly.